# How to create new column with values counting up every 9th value with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

as I realized that my project cannot be implemented with Excel I am now forced to learn working with SQL. Because I'm used to Excel VBA I am already failing at simple tasks.

In a table of my SQL Database I wanna create a new column with values counting up (ASC) but it shouldn't count up like 1,2,3,4,...it rather should increase the value by 1 every 9th value. 
So if we start in row 1 with Value 1 than every row until row 9 in this column should countain value 1 followed by an increase in row 10 by 1. So value 2 should be shown until row 18.....in total this should end in row 306.

Is anybody able to help me? I have no clue at all..

THANK YOU FOR YOU HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first simply add a column in your table and then update that column with a simple mathematics formula  -

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET NEW_COL = CEILING(((ID-1)/9)+1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Seems like a promising approach but as I am new to SQL I have already problems adding a new column in SSMS. I always get msg 2705: "Column names in each table must be unique. Column name Y in table X is specified more than once." I even tried names like "zugadsvbcsdn" but it does not work at all...my code:      ALTER TABLE [X]
   ADD Y int;

Comment: The error says you are adding a column name which is already in table. Please try with other name.

Comment: I know but it isn't? No matter which characters I type in, this error always occurs. But I am pretty sure that for example "zugadsvbcsdn" is not already in my table

Comment: Can you please post the whole table structure and the column you want to add.

Comment: I have finally found out what my problem was and I entered your proposed code filling in my specific names but what do I have to do with ID? It says invalid column name..which column should I replace for ID?

Comment: Is there any identity column in your table?